# Dangerous feature on a new 20" wheel kids bike? EZBuild pedals

Tags: safety, drivetrain, mechanical

TLDR: Rather than threading a pedal directly into the crank arm this bike maker has an EZBuild feature.   The pedal is threaded into a cast aluminum part at the factory that rotates around the crank arm. When shipped the pedals are in an upright position. When assembled the pedals is rotated to the correct orientation and held there by a spring and a pin.
Is this safe?

The pedals come already installed on the bicycle and look like this:
[image]

With the rubber boot off here's another angle:
[image]
The pedal is parallel to the frame rather than perpendicular.

To get the bike ready to use the pedal is rotated 90 degrees where the mechanism will be held in place by a pin and a spring.

Here is a picture of the pedal turned to a 45 degree angle:
[image]

End view with the pedal ready to ride:
[image]

The pedal mechanism with the boot moved out of the way:
[image]

The bike with the pedal ready to ride:
[image]

Bike makers want to ship a bike in a box that is as narrow as possible so they can get the most bikes possible in a shipping container or truck.
To keep the box narrow the pedals are not installed on the bicycle but are included in the parts box.

This feature is designed to:

- Make assembly easier
- Allow the factory to install the pedals rather than risk that the pedals be installed wrong and strip threads.
- Keep the box narrow for optimum shipping.

But does this feature compromise rider safety?

Comment: That looks like a pretty robust connection to me. What, exactly is your concern about it? Do you think something's going to fall off or break? That the pedal could suddenly pop into the folded position? For a cheap, discount store bike, that seems to remove one of the areas where the decidedly not-a-bike-shop employees who get paid to assemble these could screw it up.

Comment: I consider this is a useful feature for easy storage at home or for transport in a car, not just for shipping. I asume the pedal needs and adult's strong hand to fold it, as such, i'ts not likely that the "normal"use a kid may give the bike could result in unintended folding. I've seen worse pedal folding mechanisms in bikes intended for adults. The ideal combo should include a similar mechanism to turn the handlebar parallel to the from wheel. Again, If your kid is doing stunt riding, then this is at all not the adequate bike.

Comment: No low end manufacturer is going to create a relatively expensive pedal folding system to save money on shipping and packaging. Just get a min wage peon at Walmart or wherever the bike ends up to install pedals. I’m guessing this is to allow kids learning to ride to scoot the bike with their feet to learn some balance before learning to pedal.

Comment: @FreeMan I've seen how hard kids can ride a 20 inch bike. The cast aluminum portion concerns me most. The only thing preventing this pedal from freely spinning around the crank arm is a small notch in a cast aluminum part. Cast aluminum is sometimes brittle.

Comment: @Jahaziel The pedal is not meant to be folded back to the vertical position after being locked in place. It cannot go back to folded using hand strength.

Comment: This looks like a version of folder pedals. And if you can't fold it back by hand a ten-year-old is quite unlikely to achieve that with 'built-in' strength. So that the cast Al bit won't suffer from repeated use.

Comment: @Carel *And if you can't fold it back by hand a ten-year-old is quite unlikely to achieve that with 'built-in' strength.*  But a ten-year-old jumping on the pedals sure could.  Or a pedal strike against the ground/curb/rock/tree stump/jump ramp.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus *I’m guessing this is to allow kids learning to ride to scoot the bike with their feet to learn some balance before learning to pedal.*  Such balance bikes usually come with 10"-12" wheels and are aimed at sub-three-year-olds.  Any ten-year-old caught riding like that will still be hearing about it 50 years later.  There's a kid who grew up near me when I was growing who to this day - decades later - is still known by everyone who grew up there as "Dingle".

Comment: By "cannot go back to folded using hand strength", do you mean that the spring is stronger than your entire body weight? Because I know exactly how I would go about to put my entire body weight onto my hand to fold this pedal back - and it's technically hand strength because all the force is transmitted through a single hand...

Comment: @DavidD Honestly, I think anything likely to break that pedal mount is also likely to do some significant damage to other (likely poorly made) parts of the bike.

Comment: @DavidD it's been two years now - how did your bike's pedals hold up?

Comment: @Criggie The bike belonged to someone who gave it away. I don't know what happened to it.

Comment: As far as safety is concerned: where is the front wheel brake?

Answer (score 2):

I can think of three possible reasons for this design:

First, reduce the number of bikes returned as defective because the crank arm is stripped. While this would most likely be caused by poor assembly technique some stores have a generous return policy so they take them back anyway.

Second, I can think of is there are fewer people that can competently use tools. As the things we buy become more disposable fewer people fix there own things.

Third, most likely reason is lawsuits. If a child is injured because the pedal falls off the suit will be the fault of the person or company with the deepest pockets. So while shipping cost  and packaging do add cost, litigation is a big cost of doing business.

While this design is innovative I would have concerns about an injury if the rubber boot were damaged or became misaligned. I would have thought that rotating the pin 90 degrees would lessen the chance of the pin hitting the ankle bone.

Comment: I agree that each of your reasons has a bearing on why this design was implemented. Especially the first two points. The question asks if the design is safe. In particular, safer than not making this change.

Comment: *Third, most likely reason is lawsuits.*  I'd think a new design would open a much larger potential for liability than using an industry-standard design that's been around for more than a century-and-a-half.  There's a whole lot more potential, "Ooops! We didn't think of ***THAT***!" in a new design than there is in such a long-lived industry standard.  Barring this being a reaction to a recent legal decision or new law, this wasn't done for liability purposes.

Comment: (cont) If anything, an industry-standard design that's that old would help insulate from liability - there's likely to be decades of case law saying if a pedal falls out, it's the fault of the numbskull who didn't install it right.  Motor vehicle manufactures aren't liable if you leave the lug nuts off your wheels and then hit the freeway at 80 mph.

Comment: @DavidD Well, the "safer than not making this change" is easily answered: One more component that can fail, and this component attaches to the pedal in a structurally weaker fashion than a classic crank arm. I guess that this design has a much lower breaking force than the classic crank arm. That said, I've never had a crank arm break at the pedal, so the strength of this design might be sufficient. But I think you are right in being suspicious.

Answer (score 2):

Is the EZ Build pedal safe?
This bike is sold without training wheels for kids 4 to 5 feet tall.

It depends on how aggressive the owner is when riding. Different people will classify "light" and "aggressive" in different ways, here are some descriptions.

For light street/trail riding this one way folding pedal feature will be fine. light meaning both wheels are always on the ground.

Here's the definition of riding type this bike is designed for per the [manual provided with the bike.](https://www.huffybikes.com/media/product_manual/m0004.pdf)
[image]
[image]

For moderate to aggressive riding EZ Build should be avoided.
Moderate meaning bunny hopping up curbs, jumping off curbs.
Aggressive meaning hard street/trail riding with jumps.

If the kid has ever bent a pedal axle avoid bikes with this feature.

Comment: Can you stop your kids from doing bunny hops? I wouldn't bet any money on that...

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica Thanks for your comments. I have edited my answer and removed my conclusion of "unsafe". I have also added information from the manufacturer indicating the type of riding the bike is intended for as evidence of the unsuitability of this product for medium to aggressive riding styles. Can I stop my kid from doing bunny hops? No! I would encourage them to do bunny hops and enable this behavior by purchasing a product designed for that type of riding.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, the addition of the manual citation nicely underlines your point. Even though I guess that their main intention with that warning was to strike down any claims of liability, I have found it true that many cheap bikes and components are only build to survive at most 1000km of very light use, simply because these bikes are typically not used for more than 100km (and will end their life neglected and forgotten in some cellar or shed anyways). As a consequence, these bikes/parts may fail in catastrophic fashion when they are used by a serious rider.

Answer (score 2):

This is garbage. My nine year old is an inexperienced bike rider. No tricks, no hard use. After a year the pins that lock the pedal in place have bent and now the pedal will no longer hold its position. He can’t ride the bike without his feet slipping off the pedal that hangs at a 45 degree angle. Now what? I know I bought a discount bike, but I can get one full season of use out of it?

Comment: That's awful - looks like the crank arm doesn't have any way to attach a pedal conventionally.   Could you please post a New Question and include some photos of the damage?   It may be possible to re-do the pin in place, or you might have to replace the entire crank arm.  Sadly bike pedals have weird 9/16" 20tpi threads in left and right hand, so its highly unlikely you'll have taps capable of this.  A new crank might cost more than the bike, so used would be more affordable.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/56081)

Comment: Go down to your local recycler and grab a kids bike as a donor, swap the crank form the donor onto you kids bike.  If you have a local bike coop, they will probably cost no more than 'thank you'.

Comment: My question asked if this was a safe design, guess I should have asked if it was a durable design. I was amazed at the number of commenters that thought this was a good design.